# How to fill certain cells of a column that are in the same row as another observation on another column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning

I basically have a column with postcodes and another one with neighbourhoods and I have some null values to fill on the postcode column. So first I found what neighbourhood corresponds to that postcode that is missing. Second, I found out what is the most common postcode in that neighbourhood.

Below are some of the postcodes of neighbourhood X. The mode for this specific neighbourhood is, let's say Y. What I'm trying to do is, taking the rows that have the neighbourhood X under the neighbourhood column, fill the corresponding column of postcodes where the values are null.

This is the mode for neighbourhood X. It returns the actual mode (BS8) and the full list with all the postcodes regarding neighbourhood X

```
 <bound method Series.mode of 25      BS8 

    1904    BS1 
    1919    BS8 
    2070    BS1 
    2083    BS1 
    2099     NaN
    2105    BS1 
    2228     NaN
    2256    BS1 
    2265    BS8 
    2285    BS8 
    2298    BS8
```

So in this case, I'd want to fill the nan value under postcode with the most common postcode type for HH.

```
neighbourhood      Postcode
WH                 BS9 
SB                 BS9 
HF                 BS9 
WH                 BS9 
WH                 BS9 
SB                 BS9 
HH                 nan
SGTH               nan
```

If the most common postcode for HH was, let's say Z, if want to fill it in that corresponding postcode, like this:

```
neighbourhood      Postcode
    WH                 BS9 
    SB                 BS9 
    HF                 BS9 
    WH                 BS9 
    WH                 BS9 
    SB                 BS9 
    HH                 Z
    SGTH               nan
```

After looking online I tried something like the code below, but it didn't work.

```
airbnb.postcode = airbnb.apply( 
        lambda row: "BS8 " if (airbnb.neighbourhood=="HH" & airbnb.postcode== np.NaN) else row.postcode )
```

Comment: What is the first dataframe?

Comment: @anky_91 It does not work... It returns this error: TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool] 
I had tried something like this before but had no luck

Comment: @Chris the first thing is just a part of the list of postcodes for a certain neighbourhood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.select`

data:

```
# df2:
#       neighbourhood Postcode
#     0            WH      BS9
#     1            SB      BS9
#     2            HF      BS9
#     3            WH      BS9
#     4            WH      BS9
#     5            SB      BS9
#     6            HH      BS8
#     7          SGTH      NaN

conditions = [
    ((df2['neighbourhood'] == 'HH') & (df2['Postcode'].isna())),
]

choices = [
    'BS8'
]

df2['Postcode'] = np.select(conditions, choices, df2['Postcode'])

  neighbourhood Postcode
0            WH      BS9
1            SB      BS9
2            HF      BS9
3            WH      BS9
4            WH      BS9
5            SB      BS9
6            HH      BS8
7          SGTH      NaN
```

Comment: @J.Doe here is the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) if you want further info

Comment: np.where should work too, cant believe i overlook isna with np.nan. :p

Comment: @J.Doe also note that for `nan` you cannot use `==` because `np.nan != np.nan`